# Laravel 5 - Get property from Pivot Table extra attribute

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, relationships

I have a many-to-many relationship between Part and Material models. It's working perfectly with a pivot table.

Now I just added another column to the pivot table called 'provider_id'. What I need is when a User adds a Material to a Part he also selects which provider for that Material (because Material-Provider is also a many-to-many relationship), so when I do:

```
@foreach($parts as $key => $value)
 @foreach($value->materials as $mkey => $mvalue)
  {{ $mvalue->provider_id }}
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**I get the provider ID, thats ok. But I want to get it's name instead. Something like $mvalue->provider->name. How can I do it?**

Here are my **pivot table migration**:

```
Schema::create('material_part', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->integer('part_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('part_id')->references('id')
        ->on('parts')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->integer('material_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('material_id')->references('id')
        ->on('materials')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->integer('provider_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('provider_id')->references('id')
        ->on('providers')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->timestamps();
  });
```

**Part Model:**

```
class Part extends Model
{
  public function materiales(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Material', 'material_part')->withPivot('part_id', 'provider_id');
  }
}
```

I also have the same relationship in Material model.

**Provider Model:**

```
public function materials(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Material', 'material_provider');
}
```

Every relation is working fine but accesing single Provider of each Material of each Part.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm trying with this (with no success yet)

```
public function materials(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Material', 'material_part')
            ->withPivot('part_id', 'provider_id')
            ->join('providers', 'material_part.provider_id', '=', 'providers.id');

    //SELECT * FROM `material_parte` INNER JOIN providers ON material_part.provider_id = providers.id
```

}

Answer (score 1):

for getting values from `pivot` table you use `pivot->propertyName`

```
@foreach($parts as $key => $value)
 @foreach($value->materials as  $mvalue)
   {{ $mvalue->pivot-> provider_id }}
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I just got it:

```
public function materiales(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Material', 'material_part')
            ->withPivot('part_id', 'provider_id')
            ->join('providers', 'material_part.provider_id', '=', 'providers.id')
            ->select('providers.name as pivot_providers_name', 'materials.*');

  //SELECT * FROM `material_part` INNER JOIN providers ON material_part.provider_id = providers.id
```

}

THANKS!